# Files not visible from my PC

Tags: android

I have an android 4.3 device and often connect it to my PC via USB so that I can view files created by one of my apps. Strangely though, it seems that not all files on the android file system are visible. After much searching I came across [this page](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-files-to-androids-media-library-using-the-mediascanner/) which (correct me if I'm wrong) suggests that if I call MediaScannerConnection.scanFile, with the path I'm interested in, then it would make all files in those directories visible. I have implemented the code as follows:

```
void make_files_in_directory_visible_on_pc(String directory)
{
    Log.i("xx","make_files_in_directory_visible_on_pc: dir=["+directory+"]");
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
          getApplicationContext(),
          new String[]{ directory }, // array of paths
          null, // mime types
          new OnScanCompletedListener() {
             @Override
             public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
             {
                Log.i("xx","file " + path + " was scanned successfully: " + uri);
             }
          });
}
```

My app saves its files in Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() which, on my device, is "/storage/emulated/0".

When I execute this from my app I see the following in the logs:

```
file /storage/emulated/0 was scanned successfully: content://media/external/file/2552
```

After the code has run there is no change to the list of files visible from my PC, many files are still missing.
Any ideas?

**EDIT:** FYI, I do not have a file called "2552" on that directory, or anywhere else on my device.

**EDIT:** If I execute the following:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+name_of_individual_file}, null, null);
```

Then that single file does indeed become visible, but I want to achieve this for *all* files in the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out...

```
void make_files_in_directory_visible_on_pc(String path)
{   
    File f = new File(path);        
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {file[i].getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
    }
}
```